# pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0

Tags: python, windows, exception

I have my code while at the end, when it is supposed to maximize a window, I get this exceptions instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\teste\tentativa_completo.py", line 381, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 822, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 693, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\teste\tentativa_completo.py", line 273, in my_task
    window.activate()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 246, in activate
    _raiseWithLastError()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 99, in _raiseWithLastError
    raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' % (errorCode, _formatMessage(errorCode)))
pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - A operação foi concluída com êxito.
PS C:\Users\HP\Downloads\teste>
```

```
program_title = "1xWin"
window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(program_title)[0]

          
if window:
   window.maximize()
   window.activate()
else:
   print(f"O programa {program_title} não está em execução.")
```

Can someone help me understand how to solve this? Thanks

I really don't know what to try.